# Brier Score of a Prediction, Mathematical Notation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, notation, scoring-rules

I am currently working on a logistic regression model that is fitted on the base of a training set ($D_0$) and is used to predict the outcome (0 or 1) of an independent test set ($D_1$). As an prediction accuracy measure I want to use the Brier score (lets abbreviate it by $BS$).

In this context, how could one write the following in mathematical notation:

"The Brier score that results from $M_0$, whose parameters were estimated on the base of the data set $D_0$, predicting the outcomes of the data set $D_1$"

Would the following be correct? :

$$
BS(D_1|M_0,D_0)
$$

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

It is much easier to describe the Brier score in terms of what it actually is:

$$ BS = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)^2$$

It's quite intuitive, and writing the expression out consumes very little text. We rarely talk about how important it is to cut out unnecessary notation.

If you *must* have notation, I wouldn't agree with what you've written out. An important point is that the model is *not* a random quantity, so it doesn't make sense to put it on the RHS of the conditioning operator |. Or if you're a fully parametric Bayesian, the set of posterior model parameters would be a random quantity and there's no reason for the training data to be on the RHS. And let's not even talk about non-parametric Bayesian! I would prefer $BS(Y, \hat{Y})$ to denote the Brier Score.

Comment: The score in this reply, i.e, $\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2$ suffers from the fact that it increases with the number of forecasts $n$ and thus does not have a fixed range.
The original score given by [Brier (1950)](https://doi.org/10.1175/1520-0493(1950)078%3C0001:VOFEIT%3E2.0.CO;2) is $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^r \sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{p}_{ij} - x_{ij})^2$$
where $r$ is the number of classes, $\hat{p}_{ij}$ is the estimated probability of class $j$ in trial $i$, and $x_{ij}$ is 1 or 0, depending on the occurance of class $j$ in trial $i$. The normalization by $n$ guarantees a value in $[0,2]$.

Comment: @cdalitz Thanks for pointing out the missing 1/n factor. The double sum notation is a nuance only needed for polytomous data. And take care with indexing at that, in the binary case we wouldn't add both $(Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)^2$ and $(1-Y_i - 1-\hat{Y}_i)^2$.